# How to create additional columns in a pandas dataframe inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am working with pandas and would like to add columns to my dataframe from a list. Ideally I would like to iterate through my list in a for loop creating a single column in each pass.

#### Example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
'name':['Ken','Bobby'],
'age':[5,6],
'score':[1,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['name','age','score'])

new_columns = ['col1', 'col2']
```

#### Output:

```
    name    age     score
    Ken     5       1
    Bobby   6       2
```

#### Desired output:

```
    name    age     score   col1     col2
    Ken     5       1       1        1
    Bobby   6       2       2        2
```

#### Corrected solution:

```
for i in new_columns:
     df[i] = pd.Series([1,2])
```

#### Edit:

I have corrected the code to fix a typo however there is a great additional solution that does not use for loops which I intend to use in the future.

Comment: `df[i] = pd.Series([1,2])`. You need to enclose in `()`. Then again, you can just use `df[i] = [1, 2]` and not bother constructing the `Series`

Comment: @roganjosh - yes you're right, although that was merely a transcription error.

Comment: In that case, it's one you didn't fix in your edit. It also does exactly what you want, so it's hard to understand the issue. Also, the error message you posted is consistent with the "transcription error"; you cannot get `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` if that error wasn't in your actual code.

Comment: No, now your code does not throw that error. Your edit has removed the problem. Your question needs to be internally consistent for anyone else that stumbles upon it

Comment: I've rolled this back. The updated code _does not_ throw the error when you correct the apparent "transcription error". In fact, all you did was edit the code to be the suggestion in my first comment. This makes the answer meaningless and the question confusing because the issue is not repeatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing that without for loop , `assign`

```
df=df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(new_columns,[1,2]))
df
Out[84]: 
    name  age  score  col1  col2
0    Ken    5      1     1     1
1  Bobby    6      2     2     2
```

Also you do not need `Series` when creating the new columns

```
for i in new_columns:
     df[i] = [1,2]

df
Out[86]: 
    name  age  score  col1  col2
0    Ken    5      1     1     1
1  Bobby    6      2     2     2
```

---

Notice , Personally not recommend using `Series` to assign , since `pandas` is index sensitive , which means when your dataframe index is not from range 0 - n , the assign will fail. For example

```
df.index=[100,101]
for i in new_columns:
     df[i] = pd.Series([1,2])

df
Out[89]: 
      name  age  score  col1  col2
100    Ken    5      1   NaN   NaN
101  Bobby    6      2   NaN   NaN
```